# Warnings while running a script

Tags: php, html

I get those warnings while I run the script:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: varName in C:\wamp\www\dash\index.php on line 38
Notice: Undefined variable: varMsg in C:\wamp\www\dash\index.php on line 38
Notice: Undefined variable: varDate in C:\wamp\www\dash\index.php on line 38
```

In addition,I can insert details into the databaase but it inserts queries every time I refresh the page.

**the important part of the script:**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']))
{
   $varName = $_POST['formName'];
   $varMsg = $_POST['formMsg'];
   $varDate = date(d/m/y);
   $errorMessage = "";
}
//line 38
 $order ="INSERT INTO dash (name,msg,msg_date) VALUES ('$varName','$varMsg','$varDate')";  
    $result = mysql_query($order); 


?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  name
  <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="25"  />

  msg
  <input type="text" name="formMsg" maxlength="1500"  />


<input type="submit" name="formSumbit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is your question how to get rid of the warnings?  As the warnings state, they're undefined variables.  Looking at your code, this probably means that you don't have `$_POST['formSubmit']`, so none of your variables get initialized.  You should probably clarify what the question you're asking is . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if(isset($_POST['formSumbit'])) {}` needs to surround the query as well:

```
if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']))
{
   $varName = $_POST['formName'];
   $varMsg = $_POST['formMsg'];
   $varDate = date('Y-m-d');
   $errorMessage = "";
   //line 38
   $order ="INSERT INTO dash (name,msg,msg_date) VALUES ('$varName','$varMsg','$varDate')";  
   $result = mysql_query($order); 
}
```

Each time you refresh the page the queries are running but they are inserting blank values because the values are wrapped in the `if` statement. This is why you get the notices. You don't have the values because the form isn't submitted yet.

Comment: its better to use `if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']) && isset($_POST['formName']) && isset($_POST['formMsg']))`

Comment: I have one more problem, I can't see the date.

Comment: What's the datatype for `msg_date`? Is it a `date`?

Comment: Now it works thank you. There is a way to change it to left to right date? like 28-03-2013

Comment: No, not if it's a [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) datatype.

Answer (score 1):

add lines 38 and 39 inside the `if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))` statement. Currently when the page is loaded this is executed every time, however you only want to execute it when the form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']))
{
   $varName = $_POST['formName'];
   $varMsg = $_POST['formMsg'];
   $varDate = date(d/m/y);
   $errorMessage = "";
   $order ="INSERT INTO dash (name,msg,msg_date) VALUES ('$varName','$varMsg','$varDate')";  
   $result = mysql_query($order);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. not it works fine but I can't see the date. the output of the date is 00-0000-00 something like that

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code into a separate file such as "insert.php" and set your action to this, this will solve the duplicate insert problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']))
{
   $varName = $_POST['formName'];
   $varMsg = $_POST['formMsg'];
   $varDate = date(d/m/y);
   $errorMessage = "";
   $order ="INSERT INTO dash (name,msg,msg_date) VALUES ('$varName','$varMsg','$varDate')";  
   $result = mysql_query($order);
   if($result){
       header("Location: back-to-form.php");
   } else {
      echo mysql_error();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works. but the current dte doesn't appear. the output is 00-00-0000